# emma - no runtime coverage data found

Tags: ant, emma, eclemma, emmarun

I can't define why emma isn't generating the runtime coverage data.

What I'm forgetting when running the tests? 
based on the this post:
[How to change Ant script with EMMA code-coverage so it can find runtime coverage data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317679/how-to-change-ant-script-with-emma-code-coverage-so-it-can-find-runtime-coverage)

I put the instrumented classes in the top of the classpath

ant-emma.xml:

```
<!-- ====================================================================-->
<!-- EMMA SETUP -->
<!-- ====================================================================-->
<project name="Emma" basedir="." >
    <property file="./emma.properties" />
    <property name="emma.lib.dir"  location="${emma.home}/lib" />
    <property name="emma.build.dir" location="${build.dir}/emma" />
    <property name="emma.instr.dir" location="${emma.build.dir}/target" />
    <!-- directory which emma instrumentation classes will be written to -->
    <property name="emma.instr.src.dir" location="${emma.instr.dir}/src" />
    <property name="emma.instr.test.dir" location="${emma.instr.dir}/test" />
    <property name="emma.report.dir" location="${emma.build.dir}/report" />

    <!-- directory which emma coverage reports will be written to -->
    <property name="emma.data.dir" location="${emma.report.dir}/data" />
    <property name="emma.runtime.coverage.data.file" location="${emma.data.dir}/coverage.ec" />
    <property name="emma.coverage.merged.dir" location="${emma.data.dir}/final" />
    <property name="emma.coverage.file" location="${emma.coverage.merged.dir}/coverage-final.emma" />
    <property name="emma.filter" value="" />

    <path id="emma.lib.path" >
        <pathelement location="${emma.lib.dir}/emma.jar" />
        <pathelement location="${emma.lib.dir}/emma_ant.jar" />
    </path>

    <!-- Define which classes will be reported in the coverage reports (by default, we will include all classes and assume -->
    <!-- that your project's output folder is target/classes -->
    <path id="emma.coverage.classes" >
        <pathelement location="${build.src.dir}" />
        <pathelement location="${build.test.dir}" />
    </path>

    <path id="classpath.emma.run" >
        <pathelement location="${emma.instr.src.dir}" />
        <pathelement location="${emma.instr.test.dir}" />
        <pathelement location="${build.test.dir}" />
        <pathelement location="${build.src.dir}" />
        <path refid="classpath.src.compile" />
        <path refid="emma.lib.path" />
    </path>

    <taskdef resource="emma_ant.properties" classpathref="emma.lib.path" />

    <target name="emma-clean" >
        <delete includeemptydirs="true" quiet="false" verbose="false" failonerror="true" dir="${emma.report.dir}"  />
        <delete includeemptydirs="true" quiet="false" verbose="false" failonerror="true" dir="${emma.instr.dir}"  />
        <delete includeemptydirs="true" quiet="false" verbose="false" failonerror="true" dir="${emma.build.dir}"  />
    </target>

    <target name="emma-init" depends="emma-clean">
        <mkdir dir="${emma.build.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${emma.report.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${emma.instr.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${emma.report.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${emma.data.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${emma.coverage.merged.dir}" />
    </target>

    <target name="emma-turn-on" description="turns on EMMA instrumentation/reporting">
        <property name="emma.enabled" value="true" />
        <property name="emma.verbosity.level" value="verbose" />
    </target>

    <target name="emma-instrumentation-src" depends="emma-turn-on, emma-init" description="do EMMA's src instrumentation">
        <emma enabled="${emma.enabled}" verbosity="${emma.verbosity.level}" >
            <instr
                instrpath="${build.src.dir}"
                destdir="${emma.instr.src.dir}"
                metadatafile="${emma.data.dir}/metadata-src.em"
                merge="true"
                mode="fullcopy"
                >
                <filter value="${emma.filter.src}" />
            </instr>
        </emma>
    </target>

    <target name="emma-instrumentation-test" depends="emma-turn-on, emma-init" description="do EMMA's test instrumentation">
        <emma enabled="${emma.enabled}" verbosity="${emma.verbosity.level}" >
            <instr
                instrpath="${build.test.dir}"
                destdir="${emma.instr.test.dir}"
                metadatafile="${emma.data.dir}/metadata-test.em"
                merge="true"
                mode="fullcopy"
                >
                <filter value="${emma.filter.test}" />
            </instr>
        </emma>
    </target>

    <target name="run-emma-instrumentation" depends="emma-instrumentation-src, emma-instrumentation-test" />

    <target name="emma-instrumentation" depends="emma-init, run-emma-instrumentation" description="do EMMA's merge instrumentation" />

    <target name="emma-do-test" depends="emma-instrumentation" >
        <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="true" fork="true" >
            <classpath>
                <path refid="classpath.emma.run" />
            </classpath>
            <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />
            <batchtest todir="${emma.report.dir}" >
                <fileset dir="${test.src.dir}" includes="**/*Test.java" />
            </batchtest>
            <jvmarg value="-Demma.coverage.out.file=${emma.runtime.coverage.data.file}" />
            <jvmarg value="-Demma.coverage.out.merge=true" />
        </junit>
        <echo message="Emma Test Result : ${emma.report.dir}" />
        <echo message="Emma file : ${emma.runtime.coverage.data.file}" />
    </target>

    <target name="emma-run-instrumentation-merge" depends="emma-do-test" description="do EMMA's instrumentation">
        <emma enabled="${emma.enabled}" verbosity="${emma.verbosity.level}" >
            <merge outfile="${emma.coverage.file}" >
                <fileset dir="${emma.data.dir}" includes="*.em, *.ec" />
            </merge>
        </emma>
    </target>

    <target name="emma-run-report" depends="emma-run-instrumentation-merge" >
        <emma enabled="${emma.enabled}" verbosity="${emma.verbosity.level}">
            <report sourcepath="${src.dir}" depth="all" sort="+block,+name,+method,+class" metrics="method:70,block:80,line:80,class:100" >
                <fileset dir="${emma.coverage.merged.dir}" >
                    <include name="*.emma" />
                </fileset>
                <xml outfile="${emma.report.dir}/coverage.xml" depth="all" columns="class,method,block,line,name" />
                <txt outfile="${emma.report.dir}/coverage.txt" depth="all" columns="class,method,block,line,name" />
                <html outfile="${emma.report.dir}/coverage.html" depth="all" columns="class,method,block,line,name" />
            </report>
        </emma>
    </target>

    <target name="run-emma" depends="emma-run-report" />
</project>
```

Output:

```
emma-run-instrumentation-merge:
    [merge] [EMMA v2.0, build 5312 (2005/06/12 19:32:43)]
    [merge] input data path:
    [merge] {
    [merge]   C:\Temp\builds\Example\emma\report\data\metadata-src.em
    [merge]   C:\Temp\builds\Example\emma\report\data\metadata-test.em
    [merge] }
    [merge] processing input file [C:\Temp\builds\Example\emma\report\data\metadata-src.em] ...
    [merge]   loaded 40 metadata entries
    [merge] processing input file [C:\Temp\builds\Example\emma\report\data\metadata-test.em] ...
    [merge]   loaded 3 metadata entries
    [merge] 2 file(s) read and merged in 20 ms
    [merge]   merged metadata contains 43 entries
    [merge] merged/compacted data written to [C:\Temp\builds\Example\emma\report\data\final\coverage-final.emma] {in 0 ms}
emma-run-report:
   [report] [EMMA v2.0, build 5312 (2005/06/12 19:32:43)]
   [report] input data path:
   [report] {
   [report]   C:\Temp\builds\Example\emma\report\data\final\coverage-final.emma
   [report] }
   [report] source path:
   [report] {
   [report]   D:\wkp\AppUtils\src
   [report] }
   [report] processing input file [C:\Temp\builds\Example\emma\report\data\final\coverage-final.emma] ...
   [report]   loaded 43 metadata entries
   [report] 1 file(s) read and merged in 0 ms
   [report] nothing to do: no runtime coverage data found in any of the data files
run-emma:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 7 seconds
```

OUTPUT WITH DEBUG:

```
emma-do-test:
        [junit] Couldn't find junit/framework/TestCase.class
        [junit] Found D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-launcher.jar
        [junit] Found D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant.jar
        [junit] Found D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-junit.jar
        [junit] Found D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-junit4.jar
    fileset: Setup scanner in dir D:\wkp\AppUtils\libs with patternSet{ includes: [**/*.jar] excludes: [] }
    Finding class junit.framework.Test
    Loaded from D:\wkp\AppUtils\libs\junit-4.11.jar junit/framework/Test.class
    Class java.lang.Object loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
    Class junit.framework.Test loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
    Finding class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTaskMirrorImpl
    Loaded from D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-junit.jar org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/JUnitTaskMirrorImpl.class
    Class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTaskMirror loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
    Class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTaskMirror$SummaryJUnitResultFormatterMirror loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
    Class java.lang.Throwable loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
    Finding class junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
    Loaded from D:\wkp\AppUtils\libs\junit-4.11.jar junit/framework/AssertionFailedError.class
    Class java.lang.AssertionError loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
    Class junit.framework.AssertionFailedError loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
    Class java.lang.ClassLoader loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
    Class org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
    Class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTaskMirror$JUnitTestRunnerMirror loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
    Class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
    fileset: Setup scanner in dir D:\wkp\AppUtils\test with patternSet{ includes: [**/*Test.java] excludes: [] }
        [junit] Implicitly adding D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-launcher.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-junit.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-junit4.jar to CLASSPATH
        [junit] Executing 'C:\App\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\java.exe' with arguments:
        [junit] '-Demma.coverage.out.file=c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\emma\report\data\coverage.ec'
        [junit] '-Demma.coverage.out.merge=false'
        [junit] '-classpath'
        [junit] 'c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\emma\target\src;c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\emma\target\test;c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\test;c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\src;D:\wkp\AppUtils\libs\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar;D:\wkp\AppUtils\libs\joda-time-2.1.jar;D:\wkp\AppUtils\libs\junit-4.11.jar;D:\wkp\AppUtils\libs\mockito-all-1.9.5.jar;D:\wkp\AppUtils\ant\emma\lib\emma.jar;D:\wkp\AppUtils\ant\emma\lib\emma_ant.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-launcher.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-junit.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-junit4.jar'
        [junit] 'org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner'
        [junit] 'app.commons.enums.TypeFileSizeTest'
        [junit] 'filtertrace=true'
        [junit] 'haltOnError=false'
        [junit] 'haltOnFailure=true'
        [junit] 'formatter=org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.SummaryJUnitResultFormatter'
        [junit] 'showoutput=false'
        [junit] 'outputtoformatters=true'
        [junit] 'logfailedtests=true'
        [junit] 'logtestlistenerevents=false'
        [junit] 'formatter=org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.PlainJUnitResultFormatter,c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\emma\report\TEST-app.commons.enums.TypeFileSizeTest.txt'
        [junit] 'crashfile=D:\wkp\AppUtils\ant\emma\junitvmwatcher3180808930350880484.properties'
        [junit] 'propsfile=D:\wkp\AppUtils\ant\emma\junit6882722104357253846.properties'
        [junit] 
        [junit] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
        [junit] not part of the command.
    Execute:Java13CommandLauncher: Executing 'C:\App\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\java.exe' with arguments:
    '-Demma.coverage.out.file=c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\emma\report\data\coverage.ec'
    '-Demma.coverage.out.merge=false'
    '-classpath'
    'c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\emma\target\src;c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\emma\target\test;c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\test;c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\src;D:\wkp\AppUtils\libs\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar;D:\wkp\AppUtils\libs\joda-time-2.1.jar;D:\wkp\AppUtils\libs\junit-4.11.jar;D:\wkp\AppUtils\libs\mockito-all-1.9.5.jar;D:\wkp\AppUtils\ant\emma\lib\emma.jar;D:\wkp\AppUtils\ant\emma\lib\emma_ant.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-launcher.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-junit.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-junit4.jar'
    'org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner'
    'app.commons.enums.TypeFileSizeTest'
    'filtertrace=true'
    'haltOnError=false'
    'haltOnFailure=true'
    'formatter=org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.SummaryJUnitResultFormatter'
    'showoutput=false'
    'outputtoformatters=true'
    'logfailedtests=true'
    'logtestlistenerevents=false'
    'formatter=org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.PlainJUnitResultFormatter,c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\emma\report\TEST-app.commons.enums.TypeFileSizeTest.txt'
    'crashfile=D:\wkp\AppUtils\ant\emma\junitvmwatcher3180808930350880484.properties'
    'propsfile=D:\wkp\AppUtils\ant\emma\junit6882722104357253846.properties'

    The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
    not part of the command.
        [junit] Running app.commons.enums.TypeFileSizeTest
        [junit] Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.026 sec
        [junit] Implicitly adding D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-launcher.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-junit.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-junit4.jar to CLASSPATH
        [junit] Executing 'C:\App\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\java.exe' with arguments:
        [junit] '-Demma.coverage.out.file=c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\emma\report\data\coverage.ec'
        [junit] '-Demma.coverage.out.merge=false'
        [junit] '-classpath'
        [junit] 'c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\emma\target\src;c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\emma\target\test;c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\test;c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\src;D:\wkp\AppUtils\libs\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar;D:\wkp\AppUtils\libs\joda-time-2.1.jar;D:\wkp\AppUtils\libs\junit-4.11.jar;D:\wkp\AppUtils\libs\mockito-all-1.9.5.jar;D:\wkp\AppUtils\ant\emma\lib\emma.jar;D:\wkp\AppUtils\ant\emma\lib\emma_ant.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-launcher.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-junit.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-junit4.jar'
        [junit] 'org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner'
        [junit] 'app.commons.utils.AppFileUtilsTest'
        [junit] 'filtertrace=true'
        [junit] 'haltOnError=false'
        [junit] 'haltOnFailure=true'
        [junit] 'formatter=org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.SummaryJUnitResultFormatter'
        [junit] 'showoutput=false'
        [junit] 'outputtoformatters=true'
        [junit] 'logfailedtests=true'
        [junit] 'logtestlistenerevents=false'
        [junit] 'formatter=org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.PlainJUnitResultFormatter,c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\emma\report\TEST-app.commons.utils.AppFileUtilsTest.txt'
        [junit] 'crashfile=D:\wkp\AppUtils\ant\emma\junitvmwatcher4273539226127863796.properties'
        [junit] 'propsfile=D:\wkp\AppUtils\ant\emma\junit7675821937325699249.properties'
        [junit] 
        [junit] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
        [junit] not part of the command.
    Execute:Java13CommandLauncher: Executing 'C:\App\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\java.exe' with arguments:
    '-Demma.coverage.out.file=c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\emma\report\data\coverage.ec'
    '-Demma.coverage.out.merge=false'
    '-classpath'
    'c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\emma\target\src;c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\emma\target\test;c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\test;c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\src;D:\wkp\AppUtils\libs\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar;D:\wkp\AppUtils\libs\joda-time-2.1.jar;D:\wkp\AppUtils\libs\junit-4.11.jar;D:\wkp\AppUtils\libs\mockito-all-1.9.5.jar;D:\wkp\AppUtils\ant\emma\lib\emma.jar;D:\wkp\AppUtils\ant\emma\lib\emma_ant.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-launcher.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-junit.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-junit4.jar'
    'org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner'
    'app.commons.utils.AppFileUtilsTest'
    'filtertrace=true'
    'haltOnError=false'
    'haltOnFailure=true'
    'formatter=org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.SummaryJUnitResultFormatter'
    'showoutput=false'
    'outputtoformatters=true'
    'logfailedtests=true'
    'logtestlistenerevents=false'
    'formatter=org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.PlainJUnitResultFormatter,c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\emma\report\TEST-app.commons.utils.AppFileUtilsTest.txt'
    'crashfile=D:\wkp\AppUtils\ant\emma\junitvmwatcher4273539226127863796.properties'
    'propsfile=D:\wkp\AppUtils\ant\emma\junit7675821937325699249.properties'

    The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
    not part of the command.
        [junit] Running app.commons.utils.AppFileUtilsTest
        [junit] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.239 sec
        [junit] Implicitly adding D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-launcher.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-junit.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-junit4.jar to CLASSPATH
        [junit] Executing 'C:\App\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\java.exe' with arguments:
        [junit] '-Demma.coverage.out.file=c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\emma\report\data\coverage.ec'
        [junit] '-Demma.coverage.out.merge=false'
        [junit] '-classpath'
        [junit] 'c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\emma\target\src;c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\emma\target\test;c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\test;c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\src;D:\wkp\AppUtils\libs\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar;D:\wkp\AppUtils\libs\joda-time-2.1.jar;D:\wkp\AppUtils\libs\junit-4.11.jar;D:\wkp\AppUtils\libs\mockito-all-1.9.5.jar;D:\wkp\AppUtils\ant\emma\lib\emma.jar;D:\wkp\AppUtils\ant\emma\lib\emma_ant.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-launcher.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-junit.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-junit4.jar'
        [junit] 'org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner'
        [junit] 'app.commons.utils.AppSystemUtilsTest'
        [junit] 'filtertrace=true'
        [junit] 'haltOnError=false'
        [junit] 'haltOnFailure=true'
        [junit] 'formatter=org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.SummaryJUnitResultFormatter'
        [junit] 'showoutput=false'
        [junit] 'outputtoformatters=true'
        [junit] 'logfailedtests=true'
        [junit] 'logtestlistenerevents=false'
        [junit] 'formatter=org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.PlainJUnitResultFormatter,c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\emma\report\TEST-app.commons.utils.AppSystemUtilsTest.txt'
        [junit] 'crashfile=D:\wkp\AppUtils\ant\emma\junitvmwatcher2828995806384576666.properties'
        [junit] 'propsfile=D:\wkp\AppUtils\ant\emma\junit7199116178610816128.properties'
        [junit] 
        [junit] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
        [junit] not part of the command.
    Execute:Java13CommandLauncher: Executing 'C:\App\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\java.exe' with arguments:
    '-Demma.coverage.out.file=c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\emma\report\data\coverage.ec'
    '-Demma.coverage.out.merge=false'
    '-classpath'
    'c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\emma\target\src;c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\emma\target\test;c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\test;c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\src;D:\wkp\AppUtils\libs\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar;D:\wkp\AppUtils\libs\joda-time-2.1.jar;D:\wkp\AppUtils\libs\junit-4.11.jar;D:\wkp\AppUtils\libs\mockito-all-1.9.5.jar;D:\wkp\AppUtils\ant\emma\lib\emma.jar;D:\wkp\AppUtils\ant\emma\lib\emma_ant.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-launcher.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-junit.jar;D:\App\eclipse-kepler-x64-V3.a\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\ant-junit4.jar'
    'org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner'
    'app.commons.utils.AppSystemUtilsTest'
    'filtertrace=true'
    'haltOnError=false'
    'haltOnFailure=true'
    'formatter=org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.SummaryJUnitResultFormatter'
    'showoutput=false'
    'outputtoformatters=true'
    'logfailedtests=true'
    'logtestlistenerevents=false'
    'formatter=org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.PlainJUnitResultFormatter,c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\emma\report\TEST-app.commons.utils.AppSystemUtilsTest.txt'
    'crashfile=D:\wkp\AppUtils\ant\emma\junitvmwatcher2828995806384576666.properties'
    'propsfile=D:\wkp\AppUtils\ant\emma\junit7199116178610816128.properties'

    The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
    not part of the command.
        [junit] Running app.commons.utils.AppSystemUtilsTest
        [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.019 sec
         [echo] Emma Test Result : c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\emma\report
         [echo] Emma file : c:\temp\builds\AppUtils\emma\report\data\coverage.ec
```

Comment: run ant with -debug and check relevant paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error when you use wrong command to generate the report. Most of the online tutorial is advocating the wrong(may by old) command, even I got this error when I used below command to generate the report:

```
{JAVA_HOME}\jre\lib\ext>java -cp emma.jar emma report -r html -in coverage.em, {ALFRESCO_HOME}\coverage.ec 
EMMA: processing input files ... 
EMMA: 1 file(s) read and merged in 60 ms 
EMMA: nothing to do: no runtime coverage data found in any of the data files
```

Correct usage of the command is(Mark there is extra "-in" in command):

```
{JAVA_HOME}\jre\lib\ext>java -cp emma.jar emma report -r txt,html -in {JAVA_HOME}\jre\lib\ext\coverage.em -in C:\t1_tempSetup\Alfresco\coverage.ec 
EMMA: processing input files ... 
EMMA: 2 file(s) read and merged in 70 ms EMMA: writing [txt] report to [{JAVA_HOME}\jre\lib\ext\coverage.txt] ... 
EMMA: writing [html] report to [{JAVA_HOME}\jre\lib\ext\coverage\index.html]
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time that I ran this, this error was occurring::

```
    [junit] Running app.commons.enums.TypeFileSizeTest
    [junit] Testsuite: app.commons.enums.TypeFileSizeTest
    [junit] Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 8, Time elapsed: 0.04 sec
    [junit] Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 8, Time elapsed: 0.04 sec
    [junit] Testcase: POS_TEST_CONVERT_TO_EB took 0 sec
    [junit]     Caused an ERROR
    [junit] Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 11
    [junit] Exception Details:
    [junit]   Location:
    [junit]     app/commons/enums/TypeFileSize.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/Integer;)V @4: ifnonnull
    [junit]   Reason:
    [junit]     Expected stackmap frame at this location.
    [junit]   Bytecode:
    [junit]     0000000: b200 8c59 c700 0757 b800 9605 323a 042a
    [junit]     0000010: 2b1c b700 62a 2db5 0007 1904 0304 54b1
    [junit]     0000020:
```

Actually I made a very bad supposition that I was doing it in the wrong way...

After a few days thinking and wasting some time to understand the problem..
I found the solution: add an argument in the VM:
(Sorry I lost the reference..)

```
<jvmarg value="-XX:-UseSplitVerifier" />
```

-In the end I just need to modify my 'emma-do-test' task:

```
<target name="emma-do-test" depends="emma-instrumentation" >
    <junit printsummary="withOutAndErr" haltonfailure="true" fork="true"  >
        <classpath>
            <path refid="classpath.emma.run" />
        </classpath>
        <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />
        <batchtest todir="${emma.report.dir}" >
            <fileset dir="${test.src.dir}" includes="**/*Test.java" />
        </batchtest>
        <jvmarg value="-XX:-UseSplitVerifier" />
        <jvmarg value="-Demma.coverage.out.file=${emma.runtime.coverage.data.file}" />
        <jvmarg value="-Demma.coverage.out.merge=false" />
    </junit>
    <echo message="Emma Test Result : ${emma.report.dir}" />
    <echo message="Emma file : ${emma.runtime.coverage.data.file}" />
</target>
```